# List-based Named Entity Recognition for search engine: how to scale?

Tags: search, memory, solr, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm working on a search engine for documents stored in Solr.

**In the user query, I want to detect Named Entitities** (persons, organizations, cities...).

The example query is:

> barack obama wife age

In this query, I want to detect that "barack obama" is a person.

Since queries are not real phrases, it is difficult for classic NER (Spacy, Stanford NER...) to work properly. 
So, I adopted **this approach**:

- store in a dictionary all entities found in the documents (sorted by decreasing length)
- loop the dictionary, to see if the user query contains entities

  ```
  def find_entities(query,entities_dict):

      entities=[]
      new_query=query.lower()

      for entity in entities_dict:
          if find_substring(entity,new_query):
              entities.append({entity:entities_dict[entity]})
              new_query = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(entity), '', new_query)
      return(new_query,entities)
  ```

**At the moment, I have about 200k entities in my Solr index**: dictionary creation takes a few minutes; after the loading, this approach works well, is fast and not so memory consuming.

**In the near future, I will have 50-100 million entities**.

I think that it will be impossible to store these entities in memory.

**How can I change my approach?** 
I'm looking for advice for the *algorithm*, the *memory management* and *data structures* to be used.

Comment: Could you run your query against a separate collection containing the entities, then run those returned against your query as you do know to find which ones are present?

Comment: Probably I can, but I think that this double query in Solr can slow down user search.
Thanks  for this idea. If you have any other advice, please share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious brute-force solution is just to make your search index distributed: you create e.g. 100 nodes with a dictionary of 1 million entities in each one, you run them in parallel, and you merge the results.

Another solution (which may be complementary to splitting the index) is to keep your entities not in a simple list, but instead in a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (aka *trie*) or in a graph of [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). These data structures speed up substring search by a lot, because they try to match *all* the entities with your query in a *single* pass, exploiting the fact that many entities have identical substrings in them.

In fact, I have used [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/) to look up a few million entities (movies, songs, actors, etc.) in short queries, and it seemed to scale very well. Formally, the time complexity of Aho-Corasick does not depend on the total number of entities, only on the number of matched entities in the concrete query. Therefore, if the search gets slow (which is unlikely), it makes sense to see what entities generate lots of false positive matches and remove them from the index. In my case, after removing very common entities such as "It" (it's a movie name!), the matcher sped up even more.

Here is an example. First, we get the entities to search for (15K cities):

```
pip install pyahocorasick
wget https://simplemaps.com/static/data/world-cities/basic/simplemaps_worldcities_basicv1.6.zip
unzip simplemaps_worldcities_basicv1.6.zip
```

Then we create the automaton that can match entities (cities):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import ahocorasick
cities = pd.read_csv('worldcities.csv')

def preprocess(text):
    """
    Add underscores instead of non-alphanumeric characters 
    and on the word boundaries in order to tell words from word substrings.
    """
    return '_{}_'.format(re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '_', text.lower()))

index = ahocorasick.Automaton()
for city in cities.city:
    index.add_word(preprocess(city), city)
index.make_automaton()
# this object can be pickled to disk and then loaded back
```

And now actually apply this index to lookup entities in the text:

```
def find_cities(text, searcher):
    result = dict()
    for end_index, city_name in searcher.iter(preprocess(text)):
        end = end_index - 1
        start = end - len(city_name)
        result[(start, end)] = city_name
    return result

print(find_cities( 'Tver’ is somewhere between Moscow and Saint Petersburg', index))
# {(0, 5): 'Tver’', (27, 33): 'Moscow', (38, 54): 'Saint Petersburg', (44, 54): 'Petersburg'} 
# the search takes about 0.1 ms
```

Naive search gives the same results but takes about 10 ms:

```
for city in cities.city:
    idx = text.find(city)
    if idx >=0:
        print(idx, city)
```

Here is [the notebook](https://gist.github.com/avidale/b4680e66c2e75a4fe0edeeb27c2e0a68) with my code.

Comment: thanks. How do you save and load the entities to be searched with pyahocorasick? Please explain...

Comment: Thank you.
Last question: using a single index for different types of entities, how can you store and use the information about the entity type? Is it possible to keep this approach and integrate this information?

Comment: In the method `add_word`, the first argument is the string to be searched for, and the second argument is an arbitrary object associated with this string (e.g. a dict with any keys). Therefore, you can keep the information about the entity type in this object.